# Wordpress: Get ACF sub page options

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom `post type` called "jobs". I've added an Options Page with ACF like this:

```
/*
 * Advanced Custom Fields sub page options
 */
if (function_exists("acf_add_options_page")) {
    acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
        "page_title" => "Job options",
        "menu_title" => "Job options",
        "menu_slug" => "job_options",
        "capability" => "edit_posts",
        "parent_slug" => "edit.php?post_type=job"
    ));
}
```

The options page itself is working as expected, but I can't figure out how to access the subpage options values.

[ACFs own docs](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/) says I can access it like this:

```
$variable = get_field('field_name', 'option');
```

But I guess that is for global options, and not sub page options.

I'm blank. Any ideas?

Comment: If you want to display it, you can just do `<?php the_field('field_name', 'option'); ?>`

Comment: That can't be right. It might be if you mean global options. I mean subpage options.

Comment: A subpage is technically still a global option. That's what ACF uses it for.

Comment: So how do I distingues an option called "Title" on one subpage options and an option called "Title" on another subpage options?

Comment: It's a bit unclear on what you are trying to do with the values you get from ACF.

Comment: I have a subpage for my custom post_type "job", where I have some translations for each field. I just want to get those fields so I can use them on my "Jobs" page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94239/discussion-between-kenneth-b-and-aibrean).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was right before my eyes.

```
$context["options"] = get_fields("options");
```

Then you can access it with Timber

```
{{ options.FIELD_NAME }}
```

Thank you @Aibrean for helping me in the right direction.